# Traverse XML nodes by name/position without needing to check bounds

Tags: xml, scala

I use the scala built in xml functionality to traverse nodes, and it is generally enough for my needs.

however, how can implement this simple one-line xpath query in scala?

```
//a[2]/b[2]/c[2]/d
```

i didn't find a simple way to do this in scala,
without the need of writing code to check that there are at least 2 items for each node sequence.

Comment: "Oops" on the duplicate marking.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a for comprehension to do it. First, add something to optional get an element by index:

```
implicit class At[T](val s: Seq[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def at(n: Int) = (s drop n).headOption
}
```

And now,

```
def findIt(n: xml.Node) = for {
  a2 <- n \\ "a" at 1 // 0-based
  b2 <- a2 \ "b" at 1
  c2 <- b2 \ "c" at 1
} yield c2 \ "d"
```

Use:

```
scala> findIt(<root><a/><a><b/><b><c/><c><d>e</d></c></b></a></root>)
res16: Option[scala.xml.NodeSeq] = Some(<d>e</d>)

scala> findIt(<root><a/><a><b/><b><c><d>e</d></c></b></a></root>)
res17: Option[scala.xml.NodeSeq] = None
```